# Trigger activity transition animation without startActivity()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-animation

I'm writing an application with actionbar (navigation) and WebView (main content) and I want trigger activity transition animation when user click on link (open another assets/local page) in Webview.
I know I can make View.startAnimation(..) but this doesn't animate an action bar.

It is possible run activity transition animation with only one Activity (and ofc without calling finish())?

Comment: call View.startAnimation with a tree root View, you can get it by calling getRootView or something...

Comment: This doesn't work exactly what i want. That animate only main Layout (without actionbar - i'm using actionbarsherlock).

Comment: so go deeper, (getParent() or something) till you reach the common root

Comment: @pskink it's working :-) thanks so much 


`Animation animationLay = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.left2right);
  ((View) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent()).startAnimation(animationLay);`

Comment: i think that getWindow().getDecorView() would work too...